# Collision detection between two BoundingBoxes in libgdx

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, libgdx, game-physics

In my libgdx game I have 3D BoundingBoxes for map and player objects. I want to find out whether they collide in 3D space. How can I do this?

Comment: Why is this "not a real question" and this here is? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247347/collision-detection-between-a-boundingbox-and-a-sphere-in-libgdx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
    public static boolean intersectsWith(BoundingBox boundingBox1, BoundingBox boundingBox2) {
        Vector3 otherMin = boundingBox1.getMin();
        Vector3 otherMax = boundingBox1.getMax();
        Vector3 min = boundingBox2.getMin();
        Vector3 max = boundingBox2.getMax();

        return (min.x < otherMax.x) && (max.x > otherMin.x)
            && (min.y < otherMax.y) && (max.y > otherMin.y)
            && (min.z < otherMax.z) && (max.z > otherMin.z);
    }
```

It's modeled after this method: https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/blob/master/src/rajawali/bounds/BoundingBox.java#L186